# Javascript / jQuery basic function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display a div on click. The function that is supposed to make the magic happen is:

```
    $(document).ready(function showGogoasa() {
      $('.gogoasa-newsletter').show();
    });
```

Unfortunately, it does nothing. Which makes me scratch my head for hours as I have done small things like this in the past and they worked. I am trying to make this modification on the website of a client.

When I check the firebug console it says the following: **ReferenceError: showGogoasa is not defined**

I tried looking on Google for this kind of error but the similar cases had this kind of issue for not declaring a variable. Well, I do not have any variables.

Comment: why didn't you pass an anonymous function?

Comment: What do you mean by anon function?

Comment: i didn't find such problem in my firebug. please use updated browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to display a div on click.

Your code is running the function on a *ready* event and doesn't give the error you describe.

Presumably (it would have helped if you had provided a complete test case) you are also trying to bind the function as a click handler, but you can't do that because you have defined it using a function expression and not a function declaration (so it doesn't create a variable called `showGogoasa` outside of its own scope).

Define the function separately, then assign call it *and* bind it as a click event handler on the ready event.

```
$(document).ready(function ready_handler() {
  function showGogoasa() { // Define it as a variable in the current scope
      $('.gogoasa-newsletter').show();
  }
  showGogoasa(); // call it now
  $("button").on("click", showGogoasa); // call it then
});
```

> Well, I do not have any variables.

That's the problem :)

Functions are first class objects and when you say `showGogoasa()` that means "Get the value of `showGogoasa` and call it as a function".

Comment: The function is applied as onclick="showGogoasa()" on an input, if this help

Comment: @Darkkz — That method of event binding introduces a new set of problems. Bind it with JavaScript as per the example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#idOfYourClickerElement').on('click', function(){
       $('.gogoasa-newsletter').show();
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

Using jsfiddle or providing more code would have been helpful.

One issue is that you are missing the click event handler. For example when the user clicks on X then Y should happen/show. The following simple example may help you to see how it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/fionaredmond/1vbagj12/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showGogoasa").click(function(){
        $(".gogoasa-newsletter").show();
    });
});
```